# Query From multiple tables sharing the same LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have a common limit for pagination which displays 30 elements per page

Now I need to get results using match against from 3 Different tables, and get 3 Fields from each of the tables.

**Table A fields** news_id, title, content
**Table B fields** events_id, title, content
**Table C fields** enc_id, title, content

And the where condition

```
WHERE ( MATCH (title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(content) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(resume) AGAINST('{$search}') )
```

Also each table row has an status field which has to be equal 1 in the where condition.

At the end I need to do a `LIMIT $start_from, 30` for the global query

Any possible way to do this?

** EDIT **

This is the query that I am using for one single table

```
"SELECT
    news_id,title,
    FROM news
    WHERE ( MATCH (title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(resume)      AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(content) AGAINST('{$search}') 

  AND noticias.status = 1 

    LIMIT 0, 30"
```

And this is what I've tried with no success. it should bring 7 rows but brings 30 some instead

```
SELECT
news.news_id AS id,
events.events_id AS id,
enc.enc_id AS id,
news.title AS title,
events.title AS title,
enc.title AS title  

FROM news, events, enc

WHERE ( MATCH (news.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(news.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(news.content) AGAINST('{$search}') 
OR  MATCH (enc.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(enc.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(enc.content) AGAINST('{$search}')  
OR MATCH (events.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(events.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(events.content) AGAINST('{$search}') ) 

AND ( news.status = 1 OR enc.status = 1 OR events.status = 1)

LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give some sample data and the expected output. A SQLFiddle will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the complete query? That gives better insight in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PrerakSola I'll see if i can upload it and link back

Comment: check your where clause..  try sth like this [  WHERE 
  ( (MATCH (news.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(news.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(news.content) AGAINST('{$search}')) AND news.status = 1) )
OR
  ( (MATCH (enc.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(enc.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(enc.content) AGAINST('{$search}')) AND enc.status = 1) )
OR
  ( (MATCH (events.title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(events.resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(events.content) AGAINST('{$search}')) AND events.status = 1) )
LIMIT $start_from, 30
  ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution so I'll share it here in case anyone else needs it.

Using `UNION`:

```
(SELECT news_id AS id, title, 'news' AS origin FROM news WHERE ( MATCH (title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(content) AGAINST('{$search}') AND status = 1) )
UNION
(SELECT events_id AS id, title, 'events' AS origin FROM events WHERE ( MATCH (title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(content) AGAINST('{$search}') AND status = 1) )
UNION
(SELECT enc_id AS id, title, 'enc' AS origin FROM enc WHERE ( MATCH (title) AGAINST('{$search}') OR MATCH(resume) AGAINST('{$search}')OR MATCH(content) AGAINST('{$search}') AND status = 1) )
LIMIT $start_from, 30
```

I use the field `origin` to know from which table each content came.